# ¿Cómo soluciono el el error de style.css al instalar tema Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress-theme

Neceisto saber como solucionar el problema que me surge al instalar un tema gratuito a Worpress, no me deja instalarlo pues supuestamente esta ausente el archivo style.css. Cuando reviso el archivo comprimido del tema, realmente no esta el archivo style.css.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que revisar si el tema no esta dentro de una carpeta dentro del zip, a veces pasa. 
Tendrás que descomprimirlo, y re comprimir la carpeta del theme que es la que tenga los siguientes archivos:

- style.css
- index.php

el instalador puede protestar pero instalar igual si faltan los siguientes archivos:

- comments.php
- screenshot.png